# How to optimize traversal of instances in class methods?

Tags: python, class, methods, instance

I checked the memory address of the `dict instance` of each instance, pointing to the same address, so it is more convenient to use the `class instance` to store the related instance name.

This is what I really wanted.

```
class MyClass:
    lens = range(10)
    instance = {}

    def __init__(self, order):
        self.order = order

    @classmethod
    def cycle(cls):
        for i in cls.lens:
            print(cls.instance[i].order)

    @classmethod
    def cls_init(cls):
        for i in cls.lens:
            cls.instance[i] = cls(i)


MyClass.cls_init()
MyClass.cycle()
```

---

I have a class `MyClass` and I have created 10 instances. I want to traverse the instances in the `class method`. The code is as follows.

Is there a more optimized method?

```
instance = {}


class MyClass:
    instances = range(10)

    def __init__(self, order):
        self.order = order

    @classmethod
    def cycle(cls):
        for i in cls.instances:
            print(instance[i].order)


for i in MyClass.instances:
    instance[i] = MyClass(i)

MyClass.cycle()
```

The result:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand

Comment: @U12-Forward I edited my question.

Comment: More optimized how?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Can it be more optimized?

Comment: What does that mean, more optimized? Faster? Less memory usage? Less lines of code?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I don't know how to describe it. I have already written the result I want. Is this clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `map`:

```
instance = dict(zip(MyClass.instances, map(MyClass, MyClass.instances)))
MyClass.cycle()
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: The variable `instance` I need is dict, what should I do?

Comment: @jaried Edited mine